# AngularJS - Show route only after all promises are resolved

Tags: angularjs

I try to load route only after promises are resolved

```
    var app = angular.module("thethaoso", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {     
            resolve: {
               message: function (repoService) {
                    return repoService.getMsg();
                }
            }
        });

}]);

app.factory('repoService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getMsg: function () {
            return "hihihi";
        }
    };
});
app.controller('teamLoadCtrl', function ($scope,message) {
    $scope.message= message;

});
```

View:

```
<div ng-app='thethaoso' ng-controller='teamLoadCtrl'>
    {{message}}
</div>
```

Always get the error Error: [$injector:unpr]http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/$injector/unpr?p0=messageProvider%20%3C-%20message%20%3C-%20teamLoadCtrl

full code at http://jsfiddle.net/c0y38yp0/5/

Am I missing something ?

Thanks all.

Comment: how are you expecting the message to be passed to the controller as an argument?

Comment: @andrew, i follow this http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved

Comment: you didn't follow that example very closely; that document uses the controller action on the `$routeProvider` rather than `ng-controller`, and passes a dependency array into the controller, not just a plain argument.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not specified a template and a controller to resolve the message object to. If you used the following syntax, it will work.

```
.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "yourView.html",
    controller: "yourController",
    resolve: {
        message: function(yourService){
            return yourService.get();
    }
}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c0y38yp0/10/

You can also resolve the promise manually in your controller like so:

```
repoService.getMsg()
    .then(function (msg) {
        $scope.message = msg;
    }
```

When the promise is resolved onto the scope as I did above, the ui will update. You can show a loading bar and use ng-hide to make the pages feel fluent while the loading occurs.

Comment: it's strange because actually on my project, i do have controller and template. I just trim down the code for clean presentation. I'll take a look at it more carefully. Thanks.

Comment: i guess the problem is I combine asp.net MVC master page with angularjs. So the updated Div is on the parent page of the View (ng-view), which means View in TemplateUrl is the child of that page. I think i need to use directive instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you resolve, service have to return promise not value.

Here is example service

```
app.factory('repoService', function ($http, $q) {
    var user = {};
    var q = $q.defer();

    $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/Serhioromano')
        .success(function(json){
          user = json;
          q.resolve();
        }).error(function(){
          q.reject();
        });


    return {
        promise: function() {
          return q.promise;
        },
        get: function() {
          return user;
        }
    };
});
```

The point here is that you return promise only. You handle how you save result. And then you can use this result like in `get()`. You know that by the time you call `get()` the `user` variable already set because promise was `resolve`.

Now in router.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, repoService) {
  $scope.user = repoService.get();
});

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', { 
          templateUrl: '/view.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl',
          resolve: {
             message: function (repoService) {
                  return repoService.promise();
              }
          }
      })
     .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

1. You return promise by `repoService.promise()`
2. In controller `repoService.get()` is triggered only after that promise resolved.

So you get your data.

Another thing in your code, you used `ng-controller`. But that thing is not binded to router and thus it avoid if it is resolved or not. You have to delete `ng-controller` and use controller router `controller: 'MainCtrl',`.

This affect your HTML

```
<body ng-app="myapp">

  <ng-view></ng-view>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/view.html">
    <p>Hello {{user.name}}!</p>
  </script>
<body>
```

You have to use `<ng-view>` to include subtemplate there and then in sub template you can use scope of the controller.

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2NgOytAeFDNf2BwPFK0g?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with the code you posted, in contrast to the code you are attempting to draw inspiration from.

When you resolve a route with the `$routeProvider`, the results are applied against an element `<ng-view></ngview>`, not a base element `<div>` as you have specified.  Without the `<ng-view>` element, there is no way for the `$routeProvider` to bind the correct controller to the correct html fragment.  Using `ng-controller` instantiates a controller instance when the dom element is rendered, and does not allow passing parameters to the controller as you have tried.  Thus your resolution error due to an unknown `message` object.  Effectively, `message` is not available outside the `$routeProvider` instance.